# In NiFi how do I remove something put into the distributedmapcache?

Tags: apache-nifi

I cannot seem to find a way to remove something that I have put into the '**distributedmapcache**'.

I am using the cache to store values each time a new flow process is executed.
Within my flow I have some processor groups that need to wait for values to be found in the cache but it is always there once the flow runs the 1st time.

***How can I completely remove the distributedmapcache?***

I'm not looking to set it to an empty value because it would still be found by the process groups that are looking for the cache.

*If distributedmapcache is not the best solution* please suggest on how I can set into memory values that I need to have set completely before the other processors can proceed.

The system with my flow is on a different network so I am not able to post a screenshot of what my flow looks like.

---

*2023-05-16 : I could not find the answer so I changed my approach to this with using a database instead.*

---

Comment: I read up on a NOTIFY processor which I'm refactoring to try and use that for the others to pickup on. Right now they were just set to try and fetch the cache, retry if it wasn't there.

Comment: NOTIFY is not the solution. Tabling this task I have until I can find a solution.

Comment: I still have not found any solution to this problem. I can set it, but I cannot delete it. It also does not appear to like if I try to set the value to just an empty value. Next will be for me to try and just set the  values into a database table and then retrieve them.

Comment: I have abandoned this approach of trying to use the cache and am using a database to house entries and then a scheduled processor to check for values from the current day from the database.